# Need help implementing simple collision detection (PYGAME)

Tags: python, windows, pygame, 2d, collision

I'm completely new to pygame and I'm struggling to implement collision detection between 'laserblast' and 'tarantula' in my game. I've read various docs on surfaces and sprites on pygame.org as well as other websites (stack overflow included) but unfortunately cant wrap my head around their concepts.

Also, I want to steer well away from classes because I'm not very familiar with them, I plan to develop my knowledge on them in later projects.

The error I keep encountering is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\jetfighterx.py", line 44, in <module>
    if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(laserblast.rect, tarantula.rect):
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'rect'
```

when a jetfighter shoots a laser towards the enemy; the game also crashes shortly after.

I really need help developing a simple solution to this problem.

Here's my code:

```
import pygame, sys, pygame.mixer 
from pygame.locals import *
import random 
pygame.init()

bif="space.jpg"
jf="spacefightersprite.png"
enemy="TarantulaSpaceFighter.png"

laser=pygame.mixer.Sound("LaserBlast.wav")
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1000,900),0,32)
caption=pygame.display.set_caption("Jet Fighter X") 
background=pygame.image.load(bif).convert()

jetfighterx=pygame.image.load(jf)
jetfighterx=pygame.transform.scale(jetfighterx, (400,400)) 
tarantula=pygame.image.load(enemy)
tarantula=pygame.transform.scale(tarantula, (100,100))
laserblast=pygame.image.load("C:\Python27\laser.png")

ex,ey=450,0
movex,movey=0,0
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
speed=300
shoot_y=0

while True:
    mx,my=pygame.mouse.get_pos() 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_ESCAPE or event.key==K_q:
                    sys.exit() 
        if event.type==MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            laser.play()
            shoot_y=my-200
            shoot_x=mx-16
    if shoot_y>0:
        screen.blit(laserblast, (shoot_x, shoot_y))
        shoot_y-=10
        pygame.display.update()
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(laserblast.rect, tarantula.rect):
               print "COLLISION DETECTED!" 

    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    screen.blit(jetfighterx,(mx-200,my-200))
    screen.blit(tarantula, (ex, ey))

    milli=clock.tick()
    seconds=milli/1000. 
    dmy=seconds*speed
    ey+=dmy

    if ey>900:
        ey=0
        ex=random.randint(50,900)

    update=pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: you are going to need classes. without them the code will be very messy and complicated. and unless you want to create a ton of variables, creating things like bullets and enemies will be tricky to achieve without classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably read up on the pygame [Surface](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_clip) class. You can use Surface.get_clip() to return a rect that you can check collisions on. Also, consider using the Rect.colliderect() method instead of the Sprite one. using that, your code would be

```
if(laserblast.get_clip().colliderect(tarantula.get_clip()))
```

And just like Thedudxo said, you should really consider using classes for your game elements.

Comment: Cheers, your solution was just what I was looking for, but now I have another issue, I want it to print "collision detected" once as soon as the tip of the laser makes contact with the enemy instead of repeatedly printing it over and over again, even before the laser has reached the enemy...do you have any ideas on how I can fix this? also I realise classes are important so I will read up more on them I once I sort this collision detection stuff out, btw I would vote up your comment if it wasnt for my low rep haha

Comment: @thebaldhen excellent! I think you should be able to accept my answer as the solution to your question, tho :)